# Is there a way to give ID to other tables based on an ID with one table?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, ms-access

I have two tables as following:

| ID | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 23 |
| 2 | bbb | 21 |
| 3 | ccc | 25 |
| 4 | ddd | 20 |

| ID | Name | Age | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | aaa | 23 | 0000 |
|  | bbb | 21 | 1111 |
|  | ccc | 28 | 2222 |
|  | ddd | 29 | 3333 |

The first table name as T1 include ID that I gave them unique ID, however from the second table T2 the ID column is empty. How can I add the same ID to the second table T2? Note: The order of the names is different, and I have about 3000 records.
Can anyone help me how to do that by Microsoft Excel or Access or by programming language python?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try with an update query having a subquery:

```sql
Update T2
Set T2.ID = 
    (Select Top 1 T1.Id 
    From T1
    Where T1.Name = T2.Name)
```

Comment: `UPDATE` queries with a subquery generally don't work with a "Recordset not updateable", you probably want to use `Dlookup` instead

Comment: Dear Gustav, Thank you for your reply. But I have this error after trying your SQL :                                                 
                                                                                                                             
       operation must use an updateable query access

Comment: If you only want to match on [Name] then try `UPDATE T2 INNER JOIN T1 ON T1.Name = T2.Name SET T2.ID = T1.ID`

Comment: Dear Gord Thompson, Thank you so much it works.